# What programming language to write extension/addon/plugin/toolbars for browsers?

Tags: browser, toolbar, add-on

What programming language are people using for writing code for addons/toolbars like (firebug, web developer, google mail checker) for:

1) Firefox
2) Chrome
3) Opera
4) Internet Explorer

Thanks in advance.